# How to conditionally add a scroll if it's needed for mupltiple divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, conditional-statements

I have multiple div with text inside sometimes two words and sometimes a big paragraph and a class of `.issue__textarea`.

I know this way if I just add a fixed height with CSS like works:

```
 overflow:hidden;height:200px; overflow-y:scroll;
```

But this way the div will have a fixed height even if the text is small and creates white space.

How to conditionally add the scrollbar, do I need to add the current "this" somewhere?

I tried this code below the condition works but it applies the styles to every div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var n = $.trim($(".issue__textarea").text()).length;  // checks the text length
  var b = $(".issue__textarea").height(); // checks the height of the class

  if (b > 20) {
    $(".issue__textarea").css({
      "overflow": "hidden",
      "height": "150",
      "overflow-y": "scroll"
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Am I getting this wrong or would `overflow-y: auto;` cover you? What it does is to show the scrollbar when needed.

Comment: Hi  @Dejan.S as I said in the description I need to add it via code. The normal way with overflow it works great if you have long paragraphs but with small text, the fixed height will be still there which creates empty space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May you need to loop through all the elements

Like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var n = $.trim($(".issue__textarea").text()).length;  // checks the text length


  $(".issue__textarea").each(function() {
     var b = $(this).height();
     if (b > 20) {
         $(this).css({
             "overflow": "hidden",
             "height": "150",
             "overflow-y": "auto"
         });
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi Kenny, this looks like it might solve my problem, but I think there are syntax errors somewhere. My visual studio code gives me syntax errors. Any idea where? Cheers for your help

Comment: line 6 =    ':' expected.

Comment: this are the syntax errors i get:

line 6 [ var b = $(this).height(); ]  =    ' : ' expected. and a ' , ' expected.

line 7 [ if (b > 20) {  ]=  ' , ' expected. and a ' ; '

line 15 the last line [  }); ] =  Declaration or statement expected.

I'm a bit new to using jQuery. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually there was a syntax error in `.each`. I just corrected it and updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for fixing it. Sadly this doesn't work for me. I created this fiddle, please have a look if you have time. Am i missing something? [link]http://jsfiddle.net/EneaP/uc39yt7p/29/

Comment: Updated my answer too... the mistake was arrow function. We should not use arrow function in jquery if we want `this` as that particular element.

Comment: Amazing! Works as needed... thank you very much @Kenny, I marked your answer as resolved but i cant upvote - im less than 15 reputation. Have a great day.